# Get highest element from ordered dictionary

Tags: c#

I have a following dictionary of enums:

```
private readonly SortedDictionary<Fruit, Vitamin> mapping = new SortedDictionary<Fruit, Vitamin>
    {
        { Fruit.Apple, Vitamin.A},
        { Fruit.Banana, Vitamin.B},
        { Fruit.Orange, Vitamin.C}
    };
```

Now I am getting a collection of fruits: `[Fruit.Orange, Fruit.Plum, Fruit.Banana]` and I want to return `Vitamin` of the most important `Fruit` - in this case `Vitamin.B`

The order of Fruits in dictionary is by importance. Some `Fruits` may be not mapped.

Comment: Get the index of each fruit in the collection by comparing it with the keys of the dictionary, and then return the dictionary value?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick :

```
SortedDictionary<Fruit, Vitamin> mapping = new SortedDictionary<Fruit, Vitamin>
{
    { Fruit.Apple, Vitamin.A},
    { Fruit.Banana, Vitamin.B},
    { Fruit.Orange, Vitamin.C}
};

List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>() { Fruit.Orange, Fruit.Banana };
var vit = mapping.First(pair => fruits.Contains(pair.Key)).Value;
```

Comment: This does not work as I expect. It gets first value from mapping using order in which Fruit enum values are defined, not by the order of elements in dictionary

Answer (score 1):

if I've understood correctly, you want to get the first vitamin from the mapping dictionary which matches your list of fruit (e.g. Orange, Banana).
Something like this?

```
 var fruits = new[] { Fruit.Orange, Fruit.Banana };

 var priority = mapping.First(t => fruits.Contains(t.Key)).Value; //B

 fruits = new[] { Fruit.Banana, Fruit.Orange, Fruit.Apple };
 priority = mapping.First(t => fruits.Contains(t.Key)).Value; //A
```

Comment: Yes, but the first means the item which is higher in code (lower index), not alphabetically

Comment: This does not work as I expect. It gets first value from mapping using order in which Fruit enum values are defined, not by the order of elements in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
            if (mapping.Any())
            {
// You might need to tell Max how to do it
                var entry = mapping.Keys.Max();
                return mapping[entry];
            }
```